# How to trigger function when user clicks away from select box?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With this [multiple select box](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) the user can select multiple options. When the user is done and clicks outside the select box I want a function called "change()" to be triggered.

I've tried ng-change and using the [options](http://dotansimha.githum.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) provided by the library but they didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Matt

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.example14model = [];
    $scope.example14settings = {
        scrollableHeight: '200px',
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: false,
      showCheckAll:false,
      showUncheckAll:false
    };
  
   $scope.myEventListeners = {
   onItemSelect: onItemSelect,
    onItemDeselect: onItemDeselect,
    onSelectAll: onSelectAll,
    onDeselectAll: onDeselectAll,
      onSelectionChanged:onSelectionChanged
 };
  
      $scope.change = function() {
       console.log("call function when user done making selections");
    };

 
 // MultiSelect Drop down select - Event
 function onItemSelect(property) {
    console.log('select > ' + property);
 }
 
 function onItemDeselect(property) {
    console.log('deselect : ' + property);
 }
 
 function onSelectAll() {
   console.log('select all');
 }
 
 function onDeselectAll() {
   console.log('deselect all');
 }
  function onSelectionChanged(){
    console.log('SelectionChanged');
  }
  
    $scope.example14data = [{
        "label": "Alabama",
            "id": "AL"
    }, {
        "label": "Alaska",
            "id": "AK"
    }, {
        "label": "American Samoa",
            "id": "AS"
    }, {
        "label": "Arizona",
            "id": "AZ"
    }];
    $scope.example2settings = {
        displayProp: 'id'
    };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/2.0.0-beta.10/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" ng-change="change()" ng-model="example14model" options="example14data"  selected-model="example14model" checkboxes="true" extra-settings="example14settings" translation-texts={buttonDefaultText:'SelectView'} events="myEventListeners"></div> <pre>Selected Model: {{example14model|json}}</pre>

</div>
```

Adding a bunch of stuff here to clear the error. Wish I could have less code for the example.

Answer (score 0):

This library implements an 'onChange' event. The version I was using was an old one that didn't use the 'onChange' event. Updating the code and using the event worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `ng-blur` directive instead of `ng-change`. `ngBlur` will run the expression when the user focuses another element on the page ([ng-blur docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)).

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect ng-blur="change()" ...> /div>
```